# more general definition of structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm practicing C and it seems very tedious having to write algorithms for essentially the same data structures but that hold different data, especially since no namespace means I have to give extralong titles to everything

for example:

```
//double matrix

typedef struct DubMatrix DubMatrix;

struct DubMatrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double *data;
};

// int matrix

typedef struct IntMatrix IntMatrix;

struct IntMatrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int *data;
};
```

I have many functions that I would like to implement dealing with (among other things) matrices of different types of numbers, like algebraic numbers, elements of finite fields, etc.

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid redoing essentially the same structs and functions over and over.

Comment: What about using a generic `void *`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri That takes care of the struct, but not the functions that do math on it.

Comment: I see ... then you can implement something similiar to [container_of](https://medium.com/@funfoolsuzi/doubly-linked-list-in-linux-source-and-the-container-of-macro-460442ce7215) but adapted to a table (the linux kernel uses it with a doubly linked list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use *tagged unions* which are basically structures containing common data, and most importantly a *tag* field denoting the type, and a union for the data itself.

It could look like

```
struct Matrix
{
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    enum
    {
        INT,
        DOUBLE
    } type;
    union
    {
        int *int_data;
        double *double_data;
    } data;
};
```

Then depending on the value of `type` you use either `data.int_data` or `data.double_data`.

---

Another possible solution is similar to the above, but instead of a union use a `void *` pointer for the data, and cast it as needed.

Comment: Im new to C and have tried to read up on this, if this lets me do math then I will accept the answer. I just don't know how I would use it in practice, so I will make another question about this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

C does not really  have the concept of generics or generic programming however there are a couple of tricks you can use.

You can use void pointers but they should be allocated big enough for the biggest thing you will store in them otherwise you will just access some place you are not supposed to.

Another thing you can use for generic-ish programming is unions which can have different variants consider following example which is one of  standard oop polymorphism examples

```c
struct triangle {...}
struct rectange {...}
union shape {struct triangle *;struct rectange *;}
enum type {triangle,rectangle}
struct shape {union shape *s,enum type type} /* this is like an interface*/

size_t area(struct shape *shape){...}
```

this looks tedious but could be easily generated through a macro